# how can i initiate "Enter" after clicking on button externally in xterm.js

Tags: terminal, xtermjs

I want to use "enter" command on my xterm.js terminal by clicking button(addEventListener("click", function ()). can anyone help me out??

Comment: xterm.js sends CR ('\r') to the PTY on pressing the enter key, just do the same.

Comment: @jerch when i use term.write('clear\r'); then this command not execute. is there any other way to execute command with button click??

Comment: You are mixing the IO channels: PTY output goes to `term.write` to print things on screen (output channel). User input from the terminal goes to PTY input, thats where you should write `\r` (input channel).

Comment: okay i understand. @jerch can you please share your experience with me, if user press 'ls' button then terminal can take 'ls' as a command through button. how can i achieve this functionality?

Comment: Then write `'ls\r'` to the PTY. You really need to understand the role of the PTY and that the terminal emulator is just a frontend for the PTY data, or we end up in circles.